# Nodejs single callback after searching from 2 mongodb collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async.js

I have 2 collections `Stud` and `Prof`.

I have a function that takes `id` as argument and returns the information accordingly if id belongs to any of this collection.

- First function call: passing `id` which belongs to `Prof` collection
- Second function call: passing `id` which belongs to `Stud` collection

Expected result: getting the `Prof` results first, and `Stud` results second.

But due to the async nature of nodejs, I always get the `Stud` results first and the `Prof` results second.

Is there anyway to accomplish this task by introducing a new variable or changing the way of querying the collections?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
var check_user_info = function(userid, callback) {
    Stud.findOne({
        '_id': userid
    }, function(err, stud) {
        if (err)
            throw err
        if (stud) {
            callback(stud);
        } else {
            Prof.findOne({
                '_id': userid
            }, function(err, prof) {
                if (err)
                    throw err
                if (prof) {
                    callback(prof);
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            })
        }
    })
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the previous answer, you can use async module to complete this task. There are many functions to control the non-blocking nature of node. Here I will recommend you to use "parallel" method. As the queries are independent of each other, it will be faster than "waterfall" method.

According to your question the code will look like this.

```
var async = require('async');
async.parallel(
[
    (cb) => {
        Stud.findOne(
            {
                _id: userid
            },
            cb
        );
    },
    (cb) => {
        Prof.findOne(
            {
                _id: userid
            },
            cb
        );
    }
],
(err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        //handle error
        return;
    }

    //result will be an array where the first element will be the result of first query and
    // second element will be the query result for the second query
    // so according to this .....

    if (result[0]) {
        //id is matched with Stud collection
        //result[0] is the student doc
    } else if (result[1]) {
        //id is matched with Prof collection
        //result[0] is the professor doc
    } else {
        //Neither Stud or Prof
    }
}
```

);

You can read about the async methods from the [asyn documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) method of [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) mudule to out from this issue

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        //your fist query method can go here
        callback(null, query_result1);
    },
    function(first_result1, callback) {
        // your second query method go here
        callback(null, query_result2);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // final result'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to your question, apply @abdulbarik post.

Here is other stuff about your actual code :

---

- Cut your request into functions
- When you are using callbacks, use them to return the error properly. Do not throw.
- You do not need to put `_id` key into quote

---

Remarks:

- Because of you are using node.js that now support ES6 (most of it), use it. Simplier to read and more efficient.

---

Sample about callbacks and function cut. I let you do the rest which is es6, waterfall handling.... You can look at Promise and Async/Await pattern tho.

```
// Check if there is a student
function check_student(user_id, callback) {
  Stud.findOne({
    _id: user_id
  }, function (err, stud) {
    if (err) return callback(err, false);

    // stud here can worth false
    return callback(false, stud);
  });
}
```

---

```
// Check if there is a prof
function check_prof(user_id, callback) {
  Prof.findOne({
    _id: user_id
  }, function (err, prof) {
    if (err) return callback(err, false);

    // prof here can worth false
    return callback(false, prof);
  });
}
```

---

```
// Get Stud not Prof info
function check_user_info(user_id, callback) {
  // Look if user_id match a stud
  check_student(user_id, function (err, result) {
    // We have an error
    if (err) return callback(err, false);

    // We have a student
    if (result) return callback(false, result);

    // Check if user_id match a prof
    check_prof(user_id, function (err, result) {
      // We have an error
      if (err) return callback(err, false);

      // We have a prof
      if (result) return callback(false, result);

      // No result at all
      return callback(false, false);
    });
  });
}
```

How you call it

```
check_user_info(user_id, function (err, result) {
  // ...
});
```

---

Example of code with promise :

```
        // Check if there is a student
        function check_student(user_id) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Stud.findOne({
              _id: user_id
            }, (err, stud) => {
              if (err) return reject(err);

              // prof here can worth false
              return resolve(stud);
            });
          });
        }

        // Check if there is a prof
        function check_prof(user_id) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Prof.findOne({
              _id: user_id
            }, (err, prof) => {
              if (err) return reject(err);

              // prof here can worth false
              return resolve(prof);
            });
          });
        }

        // Get Stud not Prof info
        function check_user_info(user_id) {
          return Promise.all([
            check_student(user_id),
            check_prof(user_id),
          ]);
        }
```

---

```
check_user_info(user_id)
  .then([
    stud,
    prof,
  ] => {
    // Handle result
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Comment: **Thanks** for making corrections in code. I appreciate the way you explained, however applied the async parallel as shown by @Shawon